# Proposal for flag: AnsweredByComment

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags

Lots of questions answered in by comments but still show up as having "no answer". This is stupid, especially since short answers might get autoconverted to comments.

Add a new flag "Answered by Comment" and filter thously flagged questions when searching for "unanswerd" questions.

Comment: I have a feeling the word "flag" here doesn't mean what I think it means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

**A comment is not an answer, so by Stack Overflow's standards, the question has not yet been answered.**

If you are able to post an answer to that question—whether based on the information in the comment or not—you should do so.

If the question should not be answered (*e.g.*, because it is off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overflow), you should flag it as such ("should to be closed"). This helps increase the likelihood that it will be closed and thus stop being presented to other users like yourself.

And, like BoltClock says, you are using "flag" in a confusing way here. Generally, "flag" refers to something that you raise on a post to indicate that it needs moderator attention. We sometimes see people flag comments for moderator attention, claiming that they should be answers, but we have no choice but to decline these flags. There is no way that a moderator can "promote" a comment to an answer, so our only choice is to decline the flag or delete the comment. Clearly the latter would be a poor choice, because it would remove valuable information from the site.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: @PatrickArtner don't delete the question. The downvotes mainly show disagreement (and don't decrease your reputation). That way, anyone having the same idea can find this question, and it's answer.