# How to filter questions I already looked into and can not help solving?

Tags: support, filtering

I am new to the "race". For filtering questions I might contribute to, I set my prefered tags and know how to filter and combine tags.

Still - my filtered list contains lots of questions I looked into and I 
- have no knowledge to help 
- what I would suggest was already suggested

Is there a way to "mark" (not flag - I learned that much in [Proposal for flag: AnsweredByComment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357745/proposal-for-flag-answeredbycomment)) especially the latter questions so they will be hidden for my personal "Questions" listing in the future?

Cool would be a feature akin to what is done to tags I dislike - i.e. showing them sortof diminished and with some kind of different background.

Looked into: [How do I filter questions -- for dummies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252377/how-do-i-filter-questions-for-dummies) which is not what I ask.

Comment: This would be nice, but probably very complex to do. I wouldn't hold my breath about it ever getting implemented. Maybe there's a browser extension that helps doing this on the client end?

Comment: If it's the question which has problems (which is more likely) that makes you unable to answer them, since they lack any of the characteristics of a good question, you could simply down vote them and filter by `score:0`

Comment: Another alternative is to use the favorite: mark as favorite those questions you can't answer and then filter out with `-infavorites:mine`

Comment: @Braiam That's a quick way to get told to knock it off by the administrators...wouldn't surprise me if doing this causes way more server load than intended.

Comment: @F.George unless the query is terribly optimized (they are not), `intags:mine -infavorites:mine score:0` isn't that costly.

Comment: @Braiam It might be costly once you do this "trick" for years and have dozens of thousands of "favorited" questions.

Comment: @F.George it would be way cheaper than any other "smart" method to do what OP wants.

Comment: I guess it depends how you're doing this, but if you search your favourite tags, find nothing worse answering, then search again several hours later, you can use `created:` in your search query. Doesn't really help if you are looking down the list of 100 questions and want to start hiding ones you cant help with.

Comment: You might also be able to find a user style that hides links you've already opened, so you could look at a question, if you cant help (or even if you can), the link wont show to you any more.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can repurpose the favorite mark for this, just favorite the question you don't know the answer to and filter it out with `-infavorites:mine`.

Comment: counterintuitive way to solve it - but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hopefully you don't decide sometime in the future you want to use the favourites, cause then you'll have it filled with a bunch of irrelevant questions

Comment: Pretty bad suggestion. Favoriting is a way of marking, but typically something you want to see later. If you *do not want* to see it later, then don't mark. It should be easy to identify *new* (nonvisited questions) with color, then just add to favorites questions you want to check later (e.g. if you are interested in answer too, or, perhaps, plan to dig into the issue and post the answer). If you have some kind of activite, e.g. commenting, then there is a list of your activites in profile, helps to remember daily stuff.

Comment: Short term relief cause problems for the long term(self learned)

Comment: @Sinatr "Favoriting is a way of marking", full stop. I've seen people using this as a "to vote to delete" list, etc.. That you use favorites one way, doesn't mean that everyone should.